# Borderless form issues

Tags: c#, winforms, borderless

I have an issue with my C# application. It's about controls on borderless form. I've created a application that works like a logging system (shows in center of the screen, has 2 textboxes, 2 comboboxes, 2 pictureboxes, form StartPosition is CenterScreen). The application works fine on almost every system, 30 - 40 people are using it, but 3 of them has a problem, that makes the app useless.

> The controls are totally moved and seems little bigger than they
>   should be, 2 of these controls are moved even outside the form - which
>   makes them inaccessible.

I've tried to set the compability mode and change the screen resolution. No luck.
All of these problematic machines has Windows 7 and default .NET 3.5.1, one has 4.0. The application was targeted for .NET 3.0 (I wanted to keep it free from dependencies on machines with Vista and newer).

I'm looking for a advice from those, who had experience with this kind of problem. I would like to keep the form borderless, its essential for its design, and keep the target framework if possible. What can i do to keep this in solid ?

Comment: Check the DPI settings on their displays, and consider changing the AutoScaleMode property on your form.

Comment: Windows has a setting that allows users to enlarge some controls in forms. It is mostly used by people with poor sight. If i remember correctly, you can reach it by right clicking your desktop, then there'll be a link below the resolution scale saying something like "make form items larger or smaller". See if those three users have changed the default settings.

Comment: Also look at their system font size. This can cascade down to control size.

Comment: @Renan This step solves the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have problems with DPI. Try increasing it on your dev machine and I bet you will see same effect. I hadn't worked with winforms for a long time, but I think you can use [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to help you out.